# Is it possible to see the open to-do's on curent date i.c.o. on the start and due date?

Tags: lotus-notes

I am using Lotus Notes 8.5.2.

I want to view the To-Do's in my calendar on the current day and not only on the due date or start date. I cannot find the setting to do that. In the previous version it worked fine.

Would anyone know how I would edit the settings to get this result?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **More > Preferences > Calendar & To Do > Display > Views** and there set the options

**Display To Do Entries** and **Display overdue To To items on the current day**.

This enables an agent called "Updatetasks" in your mail file. 
BUT: In 8.5.2 this agent is broken, as the agent security is not set correctly in that version.

It will not run...

You should update to 8.5.3, where this bug is fixed: as [SPR: IFAY8AEEP6](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/fixlist.nsf/Public/3728A182BD8CABE3852577EB00739649?OpenDocument)

For 8.5.2 there is a  work around, but this requires designer access and a designer client: change the security setting of the agent in the template to 2 and then design update will resolve the issue.

If all of this is fixed, the admin of the server can still disallow running of agents... Then this will also not work.